# installing Visual Studio 2013 ultimate on a not system disk

Tags: visual-studio

When I try to install visual studio 2013 ultimate on a non-system disk, it tries to install on the system disk and it's saying that I have no free space.

Trying to install it on my E drive, which has more than 300gb free space: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9pdhN.jpg

And that's what happens after I hit next: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CilLw.jpg

I have tried to install the other version of the visual studio 2013 ultimate, but I'm still getting this error.

How I can install visual studio 2013 ultimate on my other 'E' drive?

Comment: This isn't a programming question and thus is more appropriate on a different forum, like Super User.

Comment: It lets you install on a non-system disk but require space on your system disk for things like office integration, IIS, windows installers, package cache, etc. Also not a very good question for stack overflow.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the installer needs to install a big chunk of all the .net-framework, db-stuff, etc on C:. From my experience it isn't adviseable to install VisualStudio on another drive than C:. Nearly everytime I did this I got very strange behavoir from it.